# Is it possible to determine the location of a r2build script from within the script?

Tags: build-automation

My project structure looks like this

```
<base_dir>\build\release.r2p
<base_dir>\build\thirdparty\...
<base_dir>\src\...
<basd_dir>\release\...
```

And my build script does stuff like:

- delete `<base_dir>\release`
- copy `<base_dir>\build\thirdparty` to `<base_dir>\release`
- compile code and output to `<base_dir>\release`

I need to change the location of `<base_dir>` occasionally and I would like the r2b script to just work when I do this. Right now I have to go in and manually update `<base_dir>` when it changes.

Is it possible to reference files relative to the r2p file location? This would allow me to do something like:

- delete `<r2p_script_dir>\..\release`
- copy `<r2p_script_dir>\..\build\thirdparty` to `<r2p_script_dir>\..\release`
- compile code and output to `<r2p_script_dir>\..\release`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far there is no buildin variable support that.
i will consider it in 3.0 to support more buildin variables.